# Add lists to another list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

First i need to add the numbers given by user to a list named ***numberlist***. And then finally add it to the list of lists named ***listCollection***. After that i need to display the output from the listCollection
For example lets say at first users add numbers 2,3,4 to the list and then clicks **Add list Collection**, and then again inputs numbers 5,6,7,8 and clicks **Add to list Collection**. The ouput i want do display is

```
Collection1 : 2,3,4
Collection2 : 3,4,5
```

lets just say i want 2,3,4 in index 0 of ***listCollection*** and 5,6,7 in Index 1 of **listCollection**.
Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author sudip
 */
public class JavaApplication1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JTextField txtNotation;
    private JButton btAddlist, btAddNumber, btOutput;
    private List<List<Integer>> listCollection;
    private History history;

    public JavaApplication1() {
        initComponents();
        listCollection = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    }

    public void initComponents() {
        setSize(400, 500);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(3, 3, 3));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        txtNotation = new JTextField("2");
        txtNotation.setColumns(20);
        txtNotation.setSize(20, 40);
        btAddNumber = new JButton("Add Number");
        btAddlist = new JButton("Add List to Collection");
        btOutput = new JButton("Get");
        getContentPane().add(txtNotation);
        getContentPane().add(btAddNumber);
        getContentPane().add(btAddlist);
        getContentPane().add(btOutput);
        btAddlist.addActionListener(this);
        btAddNumber.addActionListener(this);
        btOutput.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication1().setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        List<Integer> numberlist = new ArrayList<>();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(txtNotation.getText());

        if (source.equals(btAddNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Number was added to list");
            numberlist.add(a);
        } else if (source.equals(btOutput)) {
            displayOutput();
        } else if (source.equals(btAddlist)) {
            System.out.println("Number of list was added to ListCollection");
            numberlist.clear();
            listCollection.add(numberlist);
        }

    }

    public void displayOutput() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listCollection.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Collection: " + i+1);
            for (int j = 0; j < listCollection.get(i).size(); j++) {
                System.out.print(listCollection.get(i).get(j) + ", ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Separate the logic you are having problems with from the GUI code

Comment: 5,6,7 should not be in  Index 2 of listCollection? while you mentioned both in index 1.

Comment: @prashantthakre sorry i meant 2,3,4 in index 0  and 5,6,7 in index 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton) e.getSource();
        //List<Integer> numberlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //you clear your list here
        int a = Integer.parseInt(txtNotation.getText());

        if (source.equals(btAddNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Number was added to list");
            numberlist.add(a);
        } else if (source.equals(btOutput)) {
            displayOutput();
        } else if (source.equals(btAddlist)) {
            System.out.println("Number of list was added to ListCollection");
            //numberlist.clear();   //you then added empty list to your collection (cause add doesn't copy it, it adds a reference to it)
            listCollection.add(numberlist);
            numberlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //creates new list instead of clearing old one
        }

    }
```

Result:

```
Number was added to list
Number was added to list
Number was added to list
Number of list was added to ListCollection
Number was added to list
Number was added to list
Number was added to list
Number was added to list
Number of list was added to ListCollection
Collection: 01 
2, 3, 4, 
Collection: 11 
5, 6, 7, 8,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem resides in your `actionPerformed` logic, where you reinstantiate a new `numberList` each time. When the source of the event is the `btAddList`, your list will always be empty since it just has been recreated. Numbers added by the `btAddNumber`button will never be persisted, the modified `numberList` being lost after the scope of the `actionPerfomed` method has been exited.

As said in the comments, you should aim to separate your GUI from your logic, that would have helped avoiding such mistake.

Comment: I tried initializing list on constructor, still not working!

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly unclear what you're asking, however I can see two possibilities:

1. Create a list which will have `collection1` on index `0` and `collection2` on index `1`.
2. Crete a list which will have all the elements of `collection1` and `collection2`.

First approach:

```
List<List<Integer>> listCollection = new ArrayList<>();
listCollection.add(collection1);
listCollection.add(collection2);
```

or

```
List<List<Integer>> listCollection = new ArrayList<>();
listCollection.add(null);
listCollection.add(collection1);
listCollection.add(collection2);
```

in case you want to start with index 1 **very studid** - just saying.

The second approach:

```
List<Integer> listCollection = new ArrayList<>();
listCollection.addAll(collection1);
listCollection.addAll(collection2);
```

Comment: i want to start with index 0 as default. There's a mistake in my question

Comment: instead of collecion1 and collection2 i want to use a single collection. Firstly, add collection with numbers to the listCollection,then clear the collection, and add new data to collection and then add that collection again to listCollections